# PHP - set and get method

Tags: php, oop, magento, object

How can i set and get property just like this.

```
$newObj = new Core;

$newObj->setTitle("Value"); //where title is a property from the Core object
$newObj->getTitle();
```

Im new to OOP please help.

**UPDATE**: kinda same with how magento set and get session.

Comment: Can you clarify what's the issue?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what makes the magento approach special? As it stands, the question seems to be about basic setters and getters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP provides you with so called *magic methods*. You have a [`__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and a [`__set`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) magic methods.

This enables access to otherwise inaccessible properties of a class, although not through `setFoo()` and `getFoo()` method calls. If you wish to do this, you either have to define 2 methods for each of your properties, or you can use a third magic method, [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

You get the name of the method that was called as first parameter, and an array of further parameters, so you can easily identify for which operation a call was made. A short example:

```php
public function __call($methodName, $methodParams)
{
    $type = substr($methodName, 0, 3);
    $property = lcfirst(substr($methodName, 3)); // lcfirst is only required if your properties begin with lower case letters
    if (isset($this->{$property}) === false) {
        // handle non-existing property
    }

    if ($type === "get") {
        return $this->{$property};
    } elseif ($type === "set") {
        $this->{$property} = $methodParams[0];
        return $this; // only if you wish to "link" several set calls.
    } else {
        // handle undefined type
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple public methods to set values to [class properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

https://eval.in/548500

```
class Core {

  private $title;

  public function setTitle($val) {
      $this->title = $val;
  }

  public function getTitle() {
      return $this->title;
  }

}
```

Comment: thankyou for fastreply but i already know that method. i want to do it just like magento when they are retrieving attributes from product.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple class to do this.

```
<?php

    class Core
    {

      private $title;

      public function setTitle($val)
      {
          $this->title = $val;
      }

      public function getTitle()
      {
          return $this->title;
      }
    }

    $newObj = new Core;

    $newObj->setTitle("Value");

    $newObj->getTitle();

?>
```

Comment: thankyou for fastreply but i already know that method. i want to do it just like magento when they are retrieving attributes from product.

Answer (score -1):

First you create your class like this

```
<?php
class sampleclass {
   private $firstField;


  public function getfirst() {

    return $this->firstField;

 }

public function setfirst($value) {

   $this->firstField = $value;
}
}
?>
```

after that you can used these method by generating the object of the class and calling the appropriate method.

calling the method is like this ,

```
$obj = new sampleclass();
$obj->setfirst( 'value' ); 
echo $obj->getFirst();
```

Thats it.